# Installing Ubuntu along side of Windows 8.1 on Sony Vaio

Tags: nvidia, windows, vaio, sony

I looked and didn't find help on my present laptop. Trying to dual boot on laptop, here are my stats:

```
Sony Vaio: SVF15A18CXB
OS: Windows 8.1
Processor: i7-3537U CPU @ 2 GHz
Ram: 12 GB
System: 64-bit
Pen and Touch: Full windows touch support w/ 10 touch points
Graphics: Nvidia GeForce GT 735M
```

I copied Ubuntu onto a cd and tried installing it. My computer looked at me like I was crazy. 
I manually partitioned off 20GB to run the program. Just not sure what I'm doing wrong with this project. I don't want to use a VM as I would really like to learn Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to install in BIOS boot mode and then use Boot-Repair to convert to UEFI boot. Sony's have a 'buggy' UEFI where they have modified UEFI to only boot Windows. I might download new UEFI to see if they fixed it, but I doubt it.

How you boot install media is how it installs. Or boot in UEFI or BIOS mode to install in that mode.

Shows install with screen shots for both BIOS & UEFI, so you know which you are using.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Also shows Windows 8 screens

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

Boot Repair -Also handles LVM, GPT, separate /boot and UEFI dual boot. required for UEFI & grub bug fixes

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Boot-Repair's work around for buggy UEFI is to copy shim into Windows efi folder, rename Windows efi file to a backup name and rename shim to be the Windows file name. Then UEFI thinks it is booting Windows when it really boots grub2's shim file. But then you only can boot Windows from grub menu as it has a different name.

With nVidia, you also may need nomodeset boot parameter unless you have dual video and really boot with the Intel video mode.